# Deleted VS Form Designer

Tags: vb.net

I got this problem in visual studio project were i was able to clicked the FILE menu and Clicked "Save as 'FormDesigner'" to a separate folder expecting that i would be able to save the whole project to separate folder as backup file. But i was wrong about it. And then i permanently deleted the file. When i run my project this errors appears:

> Unable to open module file
> 'D:SISBackup\StudentEnrollment.designer.vb': The system cannot find
> the file specified.
>
> Unable open module file
> 'D:SISBackup\StudentEnrollment.vb': The system cannot find the file
> specified

But luckily the form still run the code. But i can no longer open the Form from Solution explorer. This error always appear from it:

> Cannot find the file 'D:SISBackup\StudentEnrollment.vb'. It may have
> been moved or deleted.

Can anybody help me with my problem. PLEASE i don't know what to do anymore. It's my school requirement. Please help me with this.

HELP!

Comment: In future, if you want to create a backup of your solution then simply copy the solution folder in Windows Explorer. As for this case, you're just going to have to create a new form and add all the controls again, then copy the code from your old form to the new.  Just be sure that you end up with `Handles` clauses on all your event handlers.

Comment: Yes that was the worst mistake that i was committed. Now i suffer the consequences. I want to rebuild the form but the problem is, i do not know where to find the code. how will i access it? the form runs fine but my problem is, i cannot find the code to place it in a new form. Can you help me please.

Comment: Look in your recycle bin. Or look for "deleted file recovery software windows 10" on google. Generally a file can be undeleted even if its not in Recycle bin, provided some other file has not been written on the exact same location on the disk.

Comment: If you can still run the program, it's probably because you have an old EXE built before you deleted the file. If you can't build the project then you'll never be able to update that EXE. I thought you meant that you had just lost the designer code file but if you have lost the user code file as well then you may be a bit screwed. If you are unable to recover the files any other way, you can probably decompile your existing EXE to get a fairly decent approximation of the original source code.